# Is it possible to display field name in View(cshtml) using glass mapper

Tags: glass-mapper, mvc, sitecore-api

I am trying to display field name using Glass Mapper in view rendering in following format:

```
    FieldName - FieldValue
    FieldName - FieldValue
```

Ex:

- Country -  USA
- City             - New York

I can pull FieldValue from Model using GlassMapper but is there a possibility to fetch FieldName using GlassMapper or do I need to settle with Dictionary items to display in place of FieldNames

Thanks
Shiva

Answer (score 1):

It depends how you configure field names matching to class properties. If you do it using attribute, e.g.:

```
[SitecoreField(FieldName = "__Sortorder")]
public virtual int SortOrder { get; set; }
```

Then you can get field name by accessing to attribute:

```
var attribute = (SitecoreFieldAttribute) Attribute.GetCustomAttribute(Model, typeof (SitecoreFieldAttribute));
var fieldName = attribute.FieldName;
```

If you have auto mapping then filed name property will correspond to it's name.

Comment: Thanks for the response,
This is my how my model looks like. I am still not clear how can I use the field name in view rendering.
    [SitecoreType(AutoMap = true)]
    public class LegalEntity : ContentBase
    {/// <summary>
        /// Continent
        /// </summary>
        public virtual string Continent { get; set; }

        
    }
}

Comment: In that case your field name is Continent :-)

Why do you need some code to get it?

Comment: I don't want to hardcode the field name. I am able to get field value using @Model.Continent but I am trying to get field name as well in the format mentioned in question
[I need to display field name here] - Model.Continet

Comment: I am not sure what are your requirements but sounds like that maybe you want something like this (or a variant of this): https://jammykam.wordpress.com/2017/09/20/show-title-when-blank/